# Solution verification about equivalence classes.

Tags: solution-verification, relations, equivalence-relations

[image]

I'm absolutely not sure about the notations and the correct terminology and I was wondering if everything checks out..

**Question 5**

**a.**

$4^{2\ }-1$ = 15

Therefore we have 15 different partitions.

**b.**

The number of partition is the same as the number of equivalence relations.
Therefore we have 15 different relations.

**c.**

By limitation of being an equivalent relation, we have three independent partitions in $\left\{\left\{7,4,2\right\},\left\{1.3\right\},\left\{5\right\}\right\}$

with $\left\{6\right\}$ free to join any partition, or be a partition on it's own.

Therefore we have 4 equivalence relations that satisfy the condition.

The largest one is:

$R=\left\{\left(1,1\right),\left(2,2\right),\left(3,3\right),\left(4,4\right),\left(5,5\right),\left(6,6\right),\left(7,7\right),\left(7,4\right),\left(4,7\right),\left(7,2\right),\left(2,7\right),\left(7,6\right),\left(6,7\right),\left(4,2\right),\left(2,4\right),\left(2,6\right),\left(6,2\right),\left(3,1\right),\left(1,3\right),\left(6,4\right),\left(4,6\right)\right\}$

Comment: Mmm... the first part is actually a rather involved question.  The general solution is referred to as the [Bell Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number).  There are indeed $15$ partitions, however it seems very dubious that whatever calculation you did was correct to arrive at this number.

Comment: As for the second part of part (c), yes you are correct and this can be proven by noting that had $6$ been included as its own partition, it only increases the total number of pairs in the relation by $1$, having included it in with $5$ increases it by $3$, and so on... having included it with $\{7,4,2\}$ increased the total number of pairs by $7$.

Answer (score 1):

My check on the answers with discussion:

*a) How many **different** partitions of the set $\{3,19,27,40\}$ are there?*

As JMoravitz comments, the number of partitions is given by the [Bell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number), but for a set of size $4$ it's not difficult to work out *de novo*, by largest part size $P_M$:
$P_M = 1$: All parts are size $1$, #options $=1$.
$P_M = 2$: Other parts size $1$: #options $=\binom 42 = 6$.
$\phantom{P_M = 2}$: Both parts size $2$ (symmetric): #options $=\frac12\binom 42 = 3$.
$P_M = 3$: Other part must be size $1$: #options $=\binom 43 = 4$.
$P_M = 4$: Whole set is one part, #options $=1$.
Total partitions: $15$

*b) How many different equivalence relations can be defined on this set?*

As you stated, each equivalence relation can be mapped to & from a partition of the set, so again $15$.

*c) How many equivalence relations on $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ contain the set $\{(7,4),(6,6),(1,3),(4,2)\}$ but are disjoint from the set  $\{(5,4),(7,3),(3,5)\}$?*

The partition implied by the first condition implies that one part has a subset of $\{2,4,7\}$  and one part has a subset of $\{1,3\}$. The exclusions given in the second condition imply that these two parts are distinct and that $5$ is also not a member of either of them, giving us a third part that has $\{5\}$ as a subset. So the only remaining choice is where to put $6$, which is in any of the three parts identified or in a new part of its own, giving $4$ different equivalence relations.

*- Out of the equivalence relations for which the conditions hold, [state which] has the largest number of pairs in it.*

Adding $6$ as an isolated equivalence class,  $\{\{2,4,7\},\{1, 3\},\{5\},\{6\}\}$ would give the $7$ reflexive pairs with $6+2$ more pairs in the first two classes. Combining $6$ into another class would add pairs in proportion to the pre-existing size of that class, meaning that combining it into the largest class will give most pairs: $\{\{2,4,6,7\},\{1, 3\},\{5\}\}$ which has $7+12+2=21$ pairs.